# Set ImageView through Uri

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am developing Android Web app using restfull web Services.I have written Image in my system as jpg file .Now i need to set Image into ImageView.So I have tried like this

```
ImageView hotelLogo;
hotelLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewHotelLogo);
hotelLogo.setImageURI(Uri.parse("D:/images/Image0800.jpg"));
```

but it doesn't show image in my ImageView.anyone can correct my code?

Comment: What do you mean `D:`? . Is the image in asset folder?

Comment: D: is my System Drive

Comment: how can you use that ???

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to access an image located on your computer? It doesn't work that way. You either have to place the image in the res/drawable folder of your app or in your apps assets.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: if i stored in drawable folder,after stored some Images,will it take more time to load?

Comment: @XaverKapeller you can also place the image on the device's SD card or internal memory

Comment: @LenaBru Of course you can, but given his question I don' think that this is what he was looking for, and additionally your app first has to copy the data to the SD card or internal storage from the resources or assets, you can't create an app that automatically places an image there upon installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use glide or picaso library to load image from server in both also you can load local image